# Voice chat with SIP in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sip

I would like to build a web application with voice chat functionality. I heard about SIP and I thought it could help me. Please help any simple examples using SIP with Java. Spring is my current framework I'm using.
Thanks for helping!

---Edited---
Actually, my friend told me about Web RTC that can do my expecting functionality. Thanks for looking at this post.

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652049/sip-and-java-where-to-start-and-with-what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may start with: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071781/java-web-development/sip-programming-for-the-java-developer.html

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19355-01/820-3007/gfmpq/index.html

You will need also to have a SIP server. Windows (freeware): http://www.3cx.com/phone-system/sip-server/

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering why so many people just unvote and leave. It's so unresponsibility.